# How to update TableView data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I'm trying to reload the data of my `TableView`, which reloads successfully when the app launches but does not during the run time of the application. I have a view controller I store objects using `core data`, and then a second view controller in which I load up the same objects.

The `viewDidLoad()` method:

```swift
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Workout> = Workout.fetchRequest() 
do {
    let workouts = try PersistenceService.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    self.routines = workouts
    } catch {}
exerciseTableView.reloadData() // Works
```

The `reloadData()` function in this method works, as the data is refreshed every time the app starts. I tried to reload the table data using one of the buttons that I have on my second view controller that opens up a drop down menu.

The buttons action method:

```swift
@IBAction func selectRoutineButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.exerciseTableView.reloadData() // Not Working
        }
        if exerciseTableView.isHidden == true {
            animate(toggle: true, togglingTableView: exerciseTableView)
        }
        else {
            animate(toggle: false, togglingTableView: exerciseTableView)
        }
    }
```

I originally did not have the `DispatchQueue` line, but after trying to find a solution I added it. However the table data is still not changing when I press the button.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You have to fetch updated data from your local storage and then try to reload tableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
@IBAction func selectRoutineButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Workout> = Workout.fetchRequest() 
do {
    let workouts = try PersistenceService.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    self.routines = workouts
    } catch {}

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.exerciseTableView.reloadData() // Not Working
    }
    if exerciseTableView.isHidden == true {
        animate(toggle: true, togglingTableView: exerciseTableView)
    }
    else {
        animate(toggle: false, togglingTableView: exerciseTableView)
    }
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: This works. I added the fetchRequest block to it's own method and then called this method from both the viewDidLoad() and the selectRoutineButtonPressed(). Thank you.